# Determine if series converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Very simple example. Nothing special I guess. I need to look for convergence here.

$$ \sum_{n \geq 0}^{} \frac{n-2}{2n^3+5n-3} $$

My approach would be to find a sum which is greater than this sum and transform the equation like

$$ \sum_{n \geq 0}^{} \frac{n}{2n^3} \leq \sum_{n \geq 0}^{} \frac{1}{n^2} $$

I know that $1/n^2$ converges so I just need to prove the above inequality?

Or which approach would be better?

Comment: One nitpick, in both of the sums of your second displayed-math environment, you might want to start with $n\geq1$. Besides that, your approach seems perfectly fine; it's how I would do it. You should justify why the sums you have are greater than or equal to the sum given, though.

Comment: and how would i justify that?

Comment: you may see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n-2<n$ and $2n^3+5n-3>2n^3$ (since $5n-3>0$ for all $n\geq1$), so $(n^3+5n-3)^{-1}<n^{-3}$. Combining the two inequalities, we have $$\frac{n-2}{2n^3+5n-3}<\frac{n}{2n^3}=\frac{1}{2n^2}.$$ Now we can apply the direct comparison test, and we see $$\sum\frac{n-2}{2n^3+5n-3}<\sum\frac{1}{2n^2}$$where the right-hand side converges, so the left-hand side must also converge.

Comment: thanks.

I have another question. i want to prove divergence of a given sum. 
so i tried to do something similiar with direct comparison. is sum 1/n <= sum n/7n^2 somehow true? or can it be made true?

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: If you are happy with my answer for the current question, please upvote it and accept it. To answer your second question, a similar trick works, but the inequality goes in the other direction (since $1/7<1$).

Comment: yeah but If i need to prove divergence i need to prove a series which is smaller to be divergent?!

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: That is correct. Find a series which is smaller than the one you are wanting to prove something about (i.e., divergent to $+\infty$), then prove that the series which is smaller diverges to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach: the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for convergence. You can use [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to solve the integral easily.

Integrate from $1$ not from $0$ so that the integral is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Direct comparison test, drop any terms that don't have N in the bottom and then use logic to see what other terms you can drop on the bottom...and go from there.